# How to set iterated values in a variable and pass in hidden variable in struts?

Tags: html, struts2

How to set values of iterator or option tag in a variable and passing to hidden variable using struts html

```
<select name="trackNo" id="trackNo" style = "font-family: verdana; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #b4a71b; color: #000; text-transform: uppercase;height:25px;width:405px;" >
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <s:iterator value = "#session.purchaseOrderList.entrySet()" var = "entry" status="rowstatus">
        <option value="<s:property default = '--' value = '#entry.value.trackNo'/>"><s:property default = "--" value = "#entry.value.trackNo"/> - <s:property default = "--" value = "#entry.value.referenceNo"/></option>
    </s:iterator>
   <s:set var="option_list" scope="request" value="#entry"/>
   <s:hidden id='myhidden' name='myhidden' value='%option_list'/>
</select>
```

Comment: you have to take the <s:set> variable inside the iterator where u can set the value and get it to hidden field.

Comment: I am not getting whatever you want to do. Plz clarify the task.

Comment: I want to store lists/values in option tag of select tag in a variable and then that variable to be passed as hidden variable. I am new to struts so dont know if i have written it right

Comment: Do you want to have all options in a single hidden tag? Why? Try to explain what do you *want* to achieve, not *how*.

Comment: There's no point to store a list of values to a hidden tag. You can always populate it before the action is executed.

Answer (score 0):

May this code will help you.

```
<select name="trackNo" id="trackNo" style = "font-family: verdana; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #b4a71b; color: #000; text-transform: uppercase;height:25px;width:405px;" >
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <s:iterator value = "#session.purchaseOrderList.entrySet()" var = "entry" status="rowstatus">
        <option value="<s:property default = '--' value = '#entry.value.trackNo'/>">
            <s:property default = "--" value = "#entry.value.trackNo"/> - <s:property default = "--" value = "#entry.value.referenceNo"/>
            </option>
            <s:set var="option_list" scope="request" value="#entry"/>
   <s:hidden id='myhidden_{%rowstatus}' name='myhidden[]' value='%option_list'/>
    </s:iterator>
   </select>
```

Comment: those iterative options are coming in table format outside dropdown

Comment: According to requirement you can set the hidden field value outside the select box because i thought this is only the solution. you have to iterate the list one more time to set it in hidden field.

Comment: values are not coming in hidden value when retrieving

Comment: i guess you want to selected value when you submit the form as selected value in Action class ??